# Clase Vector a Funcion

Tags: c++, array, matrices, clase, manejo-de-memoria

Me piden en un ejercicio, usar memoria dinamica, en la cual, debo de implementar la clase vector para generar una matriz, de la cual ya poseo: `vector<vector<int> >matrix(ord, vector<int>(ord));` sin embargo, yo deseo mandar ese vector a una funcio, sea para llenar o para realizar alguna operacion, necesito consejos de como enviarla como parametro.

Comment: No creo que necesites muchos consejos para escribir algo así: `void func(vector<vector<int>> & matrix);` o eso o la pregunta no está bien redactada

Comment: Lo que necesito, como lo mencione, es como mandar la matriz, a una funcion. Mas claro no lo pude haber escrito.

Comment: sabes pasar un entero a una función?  Pues se hace exactamente igual. Solo que en vez de un ,`int` le pasas un objeto de tipo `vector`

Comment: Pero no seria vector en mi caso, aqui es toda una matriz utilizando la clase vector.

Comment: no es una matriz sino un vector en el que cada elemento es a su vez un vector de enteros... y como si quieren ser unicornios... el único requisito es que el tipo del parametro y el del objeto a pasar han de ser el mismo o compatibles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para pasar como parámetro una matriz realizada a partir de la clase vector puedes declarar tu función a partir de un templante

```
template<typename T>
void yourFunction(vector<vector<T>> matriz)
{
    ...//Your code
}
```

sin embargo si conoces de antemano el tipo de dato de la clase vector puedes evitar el uso del templante de la siguiente manera

```
void yourFunction(vector<vector<int>> matriz)
{
    ...//Your code
}
```

Comment: Lo invito a leer los siguientes articulos: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-in-cpp-stl/ , https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/templates-cpp/

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias, esto era lo que necesitaba, me surgía saber está información. Y en especial la última, porque así llenaría la Matriz.

Comment: @EdFlores lo que necesitas es aprender las nociones del lenguaje antes de ponerte a usar objetos a lo loco. No oo tomes a mal pero es un consejo que te va a ahorrar muchos dolores de cabeza

Comment: No es que quiera usarlo, el licenciado que me imparte la clase de Programación I me exige que utilice esa cosa sin saber como mandarlo a una funcion, y exactamente, esto que busco es para intentar realizar una determinante de una matriz.